# Counting number of elements equal to 1 in DW array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I want to count the number of 1's in an array (using MASM32). In the first iteration I am getting some weird value in `EAX`. Instead of 00000000, I'm getting 00010000. Hence also getting an incorrect value in the counter `ECX`.

```
.386  
.model small  
.data  
var1 dw 0,1,1 
.code  
main PROC  
   LEA ESI, var1  
   MOV EBX, 3  
   MOV ECX, 0  
L1:CMP EBX, 0  
   JE L3  
   MOV EAX, [ESI]  
   CMP EAX, 0  
   JE L2  
   INC ECX  
L2:DEC EBX  
   ADD ESI, 2  
   JMP L1  
L3:INVOKE ExitProcess, 0  
main ENDP  
END main
```

See this image, getting 00010000 in `EAX` instead of 00000000 as content at `[ESI]`  is 0 at begining

[image: See this image getting 00010000 in EAX instead of 0000000 as ESI content is 0 at begining]

Comment: Your code is not counting the number of 1's! It is counting the numbers that are not 0. **That's very much not the same!** Instead of `CMP EAX, 0` `JE L2` `INC ECX`, you should write `CMP EAX, 1` `JNE L2` `INC ECX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined `var1` as **word** (16-bit) and not **dword**, but you are loading a **dword** (32-bit) because you load into `eax` which is a 32-bit-sized register, so you are getting the next word in memory (which is `1`) in the upper half of your dword. See this example:

```
x dw 1
y dw 2
z dw 3

# resulting memory layout:
# 01 00 02 00 03 00
# \_x_/ \_y_/ \_z_/


mov ax, [x] # you get 0001
mov eax, [x] # you get 00020001 !! because you are reading x AND y
movzx eax, word ptr [x] # you get 00000001

# 01 00 02 00 03 00
# \_x_/ \_y_/ \_z_/
# \ax_/
# \___eax___/


mov ax, [y] # you get 0002
mov eax, [y] # you get 00030002 !! because you are reading y AND z
movzx eax, word ptr [y] # you get 00000002

# 01 00 02 00 03 00
# \_x_/ \_y_/ \_z_/
#       \ax_/
#       \___eax___/
```

In your case, it's not another named variable but the second part of `var1` (you have `var1 dw 0,1,1` so you define three words with values 0000, 0001, 0001 - but the same thing applies here as with the example above).

```
var1 dw 0,1,1

# 00 00 01 00 01 00
# \___/ \___/ \___/
#  \var1 \     \var1+4
#         \var1+2
# \ax_/
# \___eax___/
```

So, either make your variable a dword using `dd` instead of `dw` (and then also increase `esi` by 4 instead of 2), or read a word by either storing it into a smaller register like `ax` or using `movzx` (or `movsx` if you need a signed value) with `word ptr`, which extends the value to fill the whole register.

```
var1 dd 0,1,1

# 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
# \__var1___/ \_var1+4__/ \_var1+8__/
# \___eax___/
```

Note that if you decide to use `ax`, then remember that loading data into it won't modify the upper half of `eax`, it will keep its previous value, so you cannot write into `ax` and then read from `eax`, because you will again get unexpected things in the upper half. You'd then need to do `cmp ax, 0` instead of `cmp eax, 0` too. You need to be always aware of what exactly (and how much) you are reading or writing.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped me a lot. Precise and easy to understand explanation!